# Excel Power Query 2013, Get Combobox Value

Tags: vba, excel, powerquery

I have a stored proc in my SQL DB which I would like to query for data via Power Query in excel. There are three parameters for this procedure for filtering data, and I would like to pass these via Power Query too. The specific parameters should come from some form controls present in my excel sheet - namely some dropdown comboboxes. I'd like to, within the Power Query M, extract the current value of the combobox and pass it as a parameter to the stored procedure.

I know it's possible to gather cell and row/column data within M, but I haven't been able to find out how to collect form data.

Is there an approach I can take for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you either use Data validation dropdowns or link the controls to cells (with an additional INDEX formula) so that M can read the values?

Answer (score 0):

**user3261018**,

you can try following approach:

Assign the combobox value to a named cell, then address it with

```
 Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="NameOfCellWithComboboxValue"]}[Content]
```